# Show months on table Header from son object using Swift3

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift3

I am getting below Json Object

```
holiDaysMap = {
    January = ({
        date = "01/01/2016";
        dayOftheWeek = Friday;
        holidayType = National;
        monthName = January;
        occation = "New Year's Day";
    }, {
        date = "01/18/2016";
        dayOftheWeek = Monday;
        holidayType = National;
        monthName = January;
        occation = “B Day";
    });
    July = ({
        date = "07/04/2016";
        dayOftheWeek = Monday;
        holidayType = National;
        monthName = July;
        occation = “I Day";
    });
}
```

can you please guide me how do display table, sections are months according leaves on cells on table view using Swift

[image: As per image i can customise table but how to show headers with months can explain please]

As per image i can customise table but how to show headers with months can explain please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a custom struct `Month` with members `name : String`, `index : Int` and `holidays = [Holiday]()`.
- Create a custom struct `Holiday` with members `date : Date`, `type : String`, `occasion : String` and two computed properties `weekday : String` and `day : String` to be able to get localized `weekday` and `day` from the date.
- Create a data source array `var months = [Month]()`.
- Enumerate the JSON dictionary. Each value is an array.
- Enumerate the array.
- Create a `Date` object from the `date` value to get the month integer (`index`).
- Check if an entry for the dictionary key (the month name) exists in `months`. If not create one and append it to `months`.
- Add the `holiday` item to the `holidays` array of the `month`.
- Sort `months` by `index`.
- In the table view the items in `months` are the sections, `name` the section names and `holidays` are the rows respectively.

Comment: Thanks......And can you please suggest to  learn like above design pattern of code tutorials